# How to call more than one api in single activity by making separate class for all volley operations

Tags: android, callback, android-volley

I have created a separate class in which I have defined all about volley and in another activity, I have directly pass URL, CONTEXT and Get Response...

but in my **NavDrawerActivity.java** how do I call the  **subCategoryJSON();** method without writing my volley code again as I have done with **mainCategoryJSON();** method in which I just simply pass the URL, method type.

Also is this a correct approach I am doing or there need to be some modification in the code, what I want is that wherever I am using API in my project and using volley for it, I don't have to write code again and again just simply pass the URL,method type

**VolleyResponseListener.java**

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {

    void onResponse(String response, String tag);

    void onError(VolleyError error, String tag);
}
```

**CustomStringRequestVolley.java**

```
public class CustomStringRequestVolley {

    private String url;
    private String tag;
    Context ctx;
    private VolleyResponseListener volleyResponseListener;


    public CustomStringRequestVolley(String url, String tag,Context ctx,VolleyResponseListener volleyResponseListener){
        this.url = url;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.ctx=ctx;
        this.volleyResponseListener = volleyResponseListener;
        sendRequest();
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("catresponse", "response " + response);
                        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        volleyResponseListener.onResponse(response, tag);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });


          stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                     5000,
                     DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                     DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

       VolleySingleton.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

**NavDrawerActivity.java**

```
public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, VolleyResponseListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      mainCategoryJSON();
       subCategoryJSON(); 
      }


  private void mainCategoryJSON() {

        CustomStringRequestVolley request1 = new CustomStringRequestVolley(URLs.categoryURL, "TAG1", this, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response, String tag) {

        switch (tag) {
            case "TAG1":
                try {
                    Log.i("Responseeeeeezaq :", response.toString() + "   " + tag);


                  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray productArray = obj.getJSONArray("categories");


                    for (int i = 0; i < productArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject productObject = productArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CategoryModelClass categoryModelClass = new CategoryModelClass();
                        categoryModelClass.setCategoryID(productObject.getInt("Category-Id"));
                        categoryModelClass.setCategoryName(productObject.getString("Category-Name"));
                        categoryModelClass.setCategoryImg(productObject.getString("Category-Image"));
                        categoryArrayList.add(categoryModelClass);

                        Log.d("zpuyi", String.valueOf(categoryArrayList));

                    }

                    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(VolleyError error, String tag) {
        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
    }


  private void subCategoryJSON() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.subcategoryURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("subcategoryJsonResponse", response.toString());

                        try {


                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray productArray = obj.getJSONArray("sub-categories");

                            for (int i = 0; i < productArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject productObject = productArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                SubCategoryModelClass subCategoryModelClass = new SubCategoryModelClass();
                                subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Id(productObject.getInt("Subcategories-Id"));
                                subCategoryModelClass.setCat_id(productObject.getInt("categories-Id"));
                                subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Name(productObject.getString("Subcategories-Name"));
                        subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Img(productObject.getString("Subcategories-Image"));
                                subCategoryModelClassList.add(subCategoryModelClass);

                                Log.d("subCategoryArraylist", String.valueOf(subCategoryModelClassList));

                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < subCategoryModelClassList.size(); i++) {
                                subcategory_id = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Id();
                                category_id = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getCat_id();
                                subcategory_name = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Name();
                             //   subcategory_desc = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Desc();
                                subcategory_image = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Img();
                                Log.d("fdsaff", subcategory_image);

                                SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                                dbHelper.insertSubCategoryProduct(subcategory_id, category_id, subcategory_name, "https://www.ecrm.sample.in/app/img/"+subcategory_image, database);
                                dbHelper.close();
                            }

                            subCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

Comment: You can Just pass the Url and get the response from the separate class file where you have written volley code. Check my answer below @Abhishek

Comment: Did you check my answer? @Abhishek

Comment: why you have deleted the answer @BrahmaDatta

Comment: I am on vacation and I thought it's not going to solve your problem. I could have fixed the problem if I am free @Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the answer correctly but you are not implementing the written custom volley class code in the activity class.

First Define the interface class for the Volley as below,

Now implement the volley interface in the java class where you have written the custom volley class as below:

**CustomStringRequestVolley.java**

```
public class CustomStringRequestVolley implements volleyCallback {

  public Context context;

  public CustomStringRequestVolley(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
   }


public interface volleyCallback {
  void onSuccess(String result);
  void onError(String error);
}

  public void callGetServer(String URL, final 
      volleyCallback callback){

    if (!checkInternetConnection(context)) {
        showNoInternetDialogue(context);
        return;
    }

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new 
     Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            callback.onSuccess(response);
          }
    }, error -> {

        if (error.networkResponse == null){

            if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Timeout.Please try again", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (error.getClass().equals(NoConnectionError.class)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Timeout.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (error.getClass().equals(NetworkError.class)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (error.getClass().equals(ParseError.class)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Parse error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (error.getClass().equals(ServerError.class)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Server Error.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                parseVolleyError(error);

            }
        }

    }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    //setting up the retry policy for slower connections
    int socketTimeout = 120000;//120000 milli seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Now use this Custom volley class in every activity you required. It reduces you 
  boilerplate code

**NavDrawerActivity.java**

```
CustomStringRequestVolley customStringRequestVolley;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point_navigation);

  customStringRequestVolley = new CustomStringRequestVolley(this); 
 }

private void subCategoryJSON() {
    customStringRequestVolley.callGetServer(URLs.subcategoryURL,new volleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

            try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        JSONArray productArray = obj.getJSONArray("sub-categories");

                        for (int i = 0; i < productArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject productObject = productArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            SubCategoryModelClass subCategoryModelClass = new SubCategoryModelClass();
                            subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Id(productObject.getInt("Subcategories-Id"));
                            subCategoryModelClass.setCat_id(productObject.getInt("categories-Id"));
                            subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Name(productObject.getString("Subcategories-Name"));
                    subCategoryModelClass.setSubCategory_Img(productObject.getString("Subcategories-Image"));
                            subCategoryModelClassList.add(subCategoryModelClass);

                            Log.d("subCategoryArraylist", String.valueOf(subCategoryModelClassList));

                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < subCategoryModelClassList.size(); i++) {
                            subcategory_id = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Id();
                            category_id = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getCat_id();
                            subcategory_name = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Name();
                         //   subcategory_desc = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Desc();
                            subcategory_image = subCategoryModelClassList.get(i).getSubCategory_Img();
                            Log.d("fdsaff", subcategory_image);

                            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            dbHelper.insertSubCategoryProduct(subcategory_id, category_id, subcategory_name, "https://www.ecrm.sample.in/app/img/"+subcategory_image, database);
                            dbHelper.close();
                        }

                        subCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {
             //show error code
        }
    });
}
```

Let me know after you try this @Abhishek

Comment: in CustomStringRequestVolley class you have not implemented methods of interface,onResponse and onError and also i am getting error on   parseVolleyError(error)

Comment: its working fine if i implement the methods of interface in  CustomStringRequestVolley like this  Override
    public void onSuccess(String result) { }

  Override
    public void onError(String error) {

   } but then where the use of this method as it is empty, also if i dont implement the volleycallback like this CustomStringRequestVolley implements volleyCallback then this approcah is also working fine @BrahmaDatta

Comment: If it's working then please accept and upvote the answer. So it reaches many people @Abhishek

Comment: i have upvoted it but my reputation is less than 15

Comment: You cannot upvote until you get some reputation.. But you can accept the answer @Abhishek